# Point geometry in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I'm creating a geometry of lines and ellipses, now I want to add points to this geometry. I'm creating Ellipses with small radius to do this. But the problem is I'm applying transforms to this geometry. So when I translate and scale, the points get a lot bigger. How do I add points to this geometry such that it doesn't gets bigger while scaling.

This is how I'm creating the point geometry:

```
public static Path PointsGeometry(List<Point> Locations, Transform transform)
    {
        GeometryGroup geometries = new GeometryGroup();
        foreach (Point Location in Locations)
        {
            geometries.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry
                {
                    Center = Location,
                    RadiusX = .5,
                    RadiusY = .5,
                }
            );
        }

        geometries.Transform = transform;

        Path path = new Path
        {
            Fill = Brushes.WhiteSmoke,
            Data = geometries,
        };

        return path;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to draw "dots" you may draw lines with zero length and round stroke caps:

```
public static Path PointsGeometry(
    IEnumerable<Point> locations, Transform transform)
{
    var geometries = new GeometryGroup { Transform = transform };

    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
        geometries.Children.Add(new LineGeometry
        {
            StartPoint = location,
            EndPoint = location
        });
    }

    return new Path
    {
        Data = geometries,
        Stroke = Brushes.WhiteSmoke,
        StrokeThickness = 2,
        StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
        StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
    };
}
```

Or with a PathGeometry instead of a GeometryGroup:

```
public static Path PointsGeometry(
    IEnumerable<Point> locations, Transform transform)
{
    var geometry = new PathGeometry { Transform = transform };

    foreach (var location in locations)
    {
        var figure = new PathFigure { StartPoint = location };
        figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(location, true));
        geometry.Figures.Add(figure);
    }

    return new Path
    {
        Data = geometry,
        Stroke = Brushes.WhiteSmoke,
        StrokeThickness = 2,
        StrokeStartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
        StrokeEndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Also is there any difference between pathgeomtery and using geometry and adding it to the path.

Comment: I would assume that a single PathGeometry is more efficient than multiple LineGeometries in a GeometryGroup, but that is most certainly irrelevant.